# SSAS - support for scoring

Tags: ssas, crm, classification, spss, ssas-2008

I am building a few data mining models to identify customers who are most likely to respond to a marketing campaign. Decision trees and neural network showed the highest lift.

I am not able to find out how I can actual score customers using those two algorithms. Please advise. (apologies if it is an obvious question)

In general, I want to select top x number of potential customers.

Answer (score 0):

Save the models as PMML files and then using the scoring wizard on Utilities or, in older versions of Statistics, use the applymodel function in the transformation system.